# Trouble retrieving QuickAction using SFDX: Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, quickaction

I'm having a problem with retrieving QuickActions via the metadata API using SFDX. I'm using the `sfdx force:source:retrieve` command with the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case.New_WRP_Case</members>
        <members>Case.New_Neuropsych_Referral</members>
        <members>Case.New_Therapy_Referral</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here is the result:

```
=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME          TYPE         PROJECT PATH
─────────────────  ───────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Case.New_WRP_Case  QuickAction  force-app/main/default/quickActions/Case.New_WRP_Case.quickAction-meta.xml

=== WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org. If it’s not new, someone deleted it from the org.
Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:QuickAction and file name:Case.New_Neuropsych_Referral.
Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:QuickAction and file name:Case.New_Therapy_Referral.
11:07:25.923 sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest /Users/ericc/Documents/repos/voyager/bhp/manifest/branch/custom-meta.xml
 ended with exit code 0
```

So, one of the QuickActions is retrieved successfully, while the other two fail. I've confirmed that the names of the failing items are correct in the manifest. The main difference between these actions is the first one (`New_WRP_Case`) creates a new related Case record and the other two (`New_Neuropsych_Referral` and `New_Therapy_Referral`) create a new record on a custom object (`Referral__c`) that is related to the case via a lookup field.

If I do a retrieve for *all* QuickActions, the referral ones aren't returned, which is also odd.